# Vue + Laravel + Amchart: Selected value does not zoom to the selected country on the map

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, amcharts, ammap

I use Laravel where I have an Amcharts' map in vue and there is a html select too with countries' name. How can solve that if I select a country then it zoom to the country on the map AND if I click to a country on the map the selected name appear on the html select too?
I could solve this with jquery (without vue) with added these lines:

```
$('#select').on('change', function() {

    var id = this.value;

    if ( '' == id ) {
        map.clickMapObject(map.dataProvider);
    }
    else {
        map.clickMapObject(map.getObjectById(id));
    }
});

map.addListener("clickMapObject", function (event) {
    document.getElementById("select").value = event.mapObject.id;
});
```

but I would like to do it in Vue and I do not really understand how should do it.
Here is my index.html

```
<div id="titles">
 <div class="container map">
     <div class="row">

             <div class="col-md-9" id="mapdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
             <div class="col-md-3">
                 <div id="listed">
                     <ul >
                          <li v-for="task in filteredCountry">
                               @{{task.title}}         
                          </li>
                     </ul>
                 </div>
                 <select class="form-control" id="select" name="select" v-model="selectedCountry">
                     <option value="">Select a country</option>
                     <option  value="All" >All</option>
                     <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
                     <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
                         <!-- More countries -->
                  </select>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Vue:

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 

 const app = new Vue({
      el: '#titles',
      data: {
           tasks: {!! $tasks !!},
           selectedCountry: "All",
      },
      created() {
           AmCharts.makeChart( "mapdiv", {
               "type": "map",
               "zoomDuration": 0.1,
               "colorSteps": 100,

               "dataProvider": {
                   "map": "worldHigh", 
                   "getAreasFromMap": true,
                   "areas": <?php echo  '' . $countCountries . '' ?>
               },

               "areasSettings": {
                   "autoZoom": true,
                   "colorSolid": "#1B144B",
                   "selectedColor": "#1B144B",
                   "color": "#4DC5AC",
               },

               "valueLegend": {
                   "right": 100,
                   "minValue": "some",
                   "maxValue": "a lot!"
               }, 

           });
      },
      computed: {
           filteredCountry: function() {
                var app = this;
                var countries = app.selectedCountry;

                if(countries === "All") {
                     return app.tasks;
                } else {
                     return app.tasks.filter(function(task) {
                          return  (countries === 'All' || task.countries === countries);
                     });
                }
           }
      },
 });

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply assign your map to a variable on your Vue component:

```
this.map = AmCharts.makeChart( "mapdiv", {});
```

Then on your input/select you can add `v-on:change=""` attribute.

```
<select v-on:change="onChange()" v-model="selectedCountry">
    <!-- Countries here... -->
</select>
```

And on your component add a method called `onChange`:

```
methods: {
    onChange: function() {
        // Here do the logic about getting the mapObject you want
        // You probaby want to use `this.selectedCountry` from your select
        // and do something with the countries id.
        var mapObject = map.getObjectById(id);

        this.map.clickMapObject(mapObject);
    }
}
```

## UPDATE:

Steps:

- `this.map = AmCharts.makeChart( "mapdiv", {` in created so that you can access outside.
- `var mapObject = this.map.getObjectById(id);` in `onChange`
- and just to be consistend with the data `map: null,` inside your data object.

https://jsfiddle.net/OzanKurt/4petgnau/22/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to solve it, but every time when I select a country on the input, I get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of undefined
    at Object.d.makeChart (ammap.js:11)
    at Vue.onChange ((index):754)
    at _c.on.change (eval at createFunction (app.js:48786), <anonymous>:3:744)
    at invoker (app.js:40129)
    at HTMLSelectElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask (app.js:39932)

Comment: I think it would be better for us to understand if you could prepare a jsfiddle example.

Comment: This is my project: https://jsfiddle.net/4petgnau/15/ 
And this is how I would like to work: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/using-html-control-select-areas-map/ 
So if I click France on select input, it zoom to france on the map.

Comment: @Dodo it al works fine, check the changes I've made, and how to reference map within your component ;)